# boolean in if statement

Tags: php

If I want to execute code only if a variable is `true`, should I have:

```
if ($option) { /* code */ }
```

or

```
if ($option == TRUE) { /* code */ }
```

Doesn't the first one imply that also values like 1, 2, 3 etc. will execute the code.

Is the second one the better option?

Comment: Side note: you can think of `===` as sort-of analogous to doing `is_bool($option) && $option`.

Comment: @Dolph Mathews: Unless comparing to something other than a boolean value.

Comment: By "sort-of", I meant "in this instance" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `===` operator. The [manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) gives a decent description of the various comparison operators.

The `===` operator compares type as well as value.

You may also be interested in the [PHP Caparison Tables](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). They will describe how the comparison operators work when comparing two different types.

Answer (score 4):

Both those statements are essentially the same since, as you pointed out, PHP evaluates several values as `true`.

If you want your comparison to match strictly boolean TRUE variables, your second statement should use:

```
$option === TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what php does its to transform to the most simple type. in this case it will convert the integer to boolean, any integer greater tan 0 will be true, so if $option has an integer greater tan zero its equivalent to a true boolean value.

check out this table to understand it better.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php